# Error: ByteBuddyAgent for ByteBuddy

Tags: java, android, byte-buddy

Unable to install ByteBuddyAgent in android

code in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.4.18'
    compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:1.4.18'
    compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.4.18'
```

code to install ByteBuddyAgent

```
ByteBuddyAgent.install();
```

This is the compilation error, since `java.lang` don't have instrument and management packages.

```
Error:(31, 35) error: cannot access Instrumentation
class file for java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android only supports a subset of the official Java API. The instrumentation API is not supported by Android what makes agent installation impossible. See the documentation for this limitation.

Comment: Thank you, Is it possible to load dynamic class byte code in android ?

Comment: Yes, this is what the AndroidClassloadingstrategy in the Android package is for.

Comment: can you help me what is ByteBuddyAgent type utility for reloading a class in Android?

Comment: It is not possible on Android, classes on Android cannot be reloaded. Not by Byte Buddy or any other tool.